# Firefox Addon SDK Error - Module `project/tests/myjs` is not found at resource

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

As I progressed with my Firefox Addon development, I wanted to restructure into logical folder structures. And for the need, I thought of keeping some .js files under a directory called "tests", the moment I try to load by adding require('tests/myjs.js'), I am thrown with an error as below:

Message: Module `myproject/tests/myjs` is not found at resource://jid1-sdfe4541dfsafssdfewf45fa-at-jetpack/myproject/tests/myjs.js

Tried numerous attempts as I did not notice any difference than what was mentioned in [official document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Module_structure_of_the_SDK#Local_Modules) - it always ended in failure and no much results online. It always worked when placed next to main.js on the same directory, but failed when in the sub directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is a bug or designed that way, but undocumented. The solution was to rename the folder. As a brute force way, just renamed the "tests" folder to something else, it worked. Worked with various folder names, but did not work with the folder name "tests".

If anyone knows why, would be better to share. Otherwise, I have my solution anyway.

Comment: Thats very interesting, probably a reserved word. Thanks for the share. This affects only sdk addons.

Comment: Still new to addon development and hence unaware of other modes. Just shared it as no good result could be found online. Any FF developer watching this can raise a bug if required.